# Phonegap Volume up and down controls

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

Hi friends I have creating an app to play an audio file apk in the apk I want to use volume up and volume down control  option but I dont know how to achieve it I have tried this solution from all this but still not working I need to increase the volume eventually I studied that volume is upto 0 to 1 . I tried like this but still not working dont know the exact way please tell me it will be very helpful to me.

```
 function setVolume()
        {
             if (my_media)
            {
                my_media.setVolume(volume);
            }
            var volume = my_media.setVolume(volume)+0.2;
            if(volume >1){
                volume = 1;
            }
             my_media.setVolume(volume);        

        }
<button data-inline="true" onclick="setVolume();">Volume Up</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure why you're doing some things in your code.

**EDIT** (i've just realised that there is not `getVolume()` method so you will have to store volume in a global variable.

I would do something like this:

```
var volume= 0.1; // global variable

function setVolume() {
    if (!my_media) return false;

    volume+= 0.2;
    if(volume> 1){
        volume= 1;
    }

    my_media.setVolume(volume);        
}
```

Comment: is this function really increses the sound of the audio file

Comment: the function you mentioned above did not increases the sound for my apk in phonegap could you tell why its not working

Comment: just edited my answer. There is actually no `getVolume()` method (which is strange). So you will need to save volume level in a global variable

Comment: Okay I wil try this let you know

Comment: still not working is there any other way to work to control the volume in phonegap?

Comment: does the `setVolume()` function get called at all?

Comment: Yes I have called it in while clicking the button I have mentioned in my question

Comment: I know you call it but does it get called? put logging in the `setVolume()` fuction to see if it gets there and prints your log.

Comment: I have checked by using an alert inside that function the alert box worked

Comment: Note: You have a `>1` check, but its lacking a `<0` check :)